# Unable to override or customize ProductController

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm using Sylius version 1.0.0-alpha.1 i followed all steps in th docs . But i'm unable to override ProductContoller in the AppBundle.

I get this error :

Attempted to load class "ProductController" from namespace "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: check the filename of your controller file or its namespace.

Comment: checked already :/